# Why does Java hang on my Mac when I try to use ImageIO?

Tags: java, macos, javax.imageio, freeze, headless

Abruptly last afternoon, my Java (Groovy, actually) started hanging in ClassLoader.load(String, boolean) while trying to call ImageIO.read(file). The stack trace indicated it was trying to load AWT related code.

In case it was an IntelliJ or Gradle issue I tried the command-line, where it still hung, but successfully ran past that point if I specified -Djava.awt.headless=true, apparently related to the -XstartOnFirstThread SWT 2013 bug, but of course that meant I was unable to display windows from the program.

This obtained even with a trivial 'only load an image' program.

Contrarily, an existing Java-based application ran happily, and a brand new user on the same machine had no problems.

Moving all my account's . files and logging out/in, and checking my environment variables for suspicious things compared with the brand new user had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know precisely WHY this was happening, but it relates directly to having previously suffered a native crash:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000131099b1b, pid=11165, tid=4867
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract.dylib+0x156b1b]  ELIST::length() const+0x5
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/tim/git/t4jhack/hs_err_pid11165.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

because I just triggered it again, and the issue resurrected immediately.

The app crash says

```
AppMain quit unexpectedly.
Click reopen to open the application again.
This report will be sent to Apple automatically
[show details] [OK] [Reopen]
```

I clicked 'OK' and 'Reopen' variously - both cause the problem.

The 'fix' I stumbled across:

In System Preferences, open the Java Control Panel, where it will say:

```
The last time you opened Java, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows.
Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?
If you choose not to reopen windows, you may have to open and
position the windows yourself.
[don't reopen] [reopen]
```

You want 'Reopen', then just OK the resulting window.

Comment: I've seen before that OS X's restore of open windows don't always play well with Java apps after a crash. But never this bad though... You should probably report this issue to Oracle.